# How do I recreate a my site for a specific user?

Tags: my-site

I am trying to recreate a user mysite, but all I get is a 404. I added a costum my site using http://sharepointologic.blogspot.pt/2013/04/branding-sharepoint-2013-my-sites-with.html feature stapeling, but the my site in question was already created, i deleted the my site of the user via site collection delete, but now the site does not recreate itself, instead it points me to a 404 page.

Answer (score 6):

Besides deleting the site collection you also must clear a value in the User Profile!

1. Navigate to the User Profile Service in Central Admin (Manage Service Applications),
2. Click "Manage User Profiles"
3. Find the profile of the user by searching
4. Click on it and select "Edit User Profile"
5. Find "Personal site:" and empty the field
6. Find "Feed service provider defined identifier" and empty that field as well
7. Click "Save and Close"

Now, when the user tries to access his/her mysite, a new one will be created

Comment: Hi Robert, I did all that, still getting 404 errors and page is not created... no clues of what else to do next

Answer (score 0):

I would try migrating the MySite using a third-party migration tool free trial to another location within the same site. Then I would delete the MySite in order to be able to create a new one and migrate the content back.

Pretty much all the 3rd party migration tools out-there offer free trial (Sharegate, Avepoint, Metalogix etc.) that would partially or completely allow you to do just that. You can simply browse SharePoint migration and you will have a large number of tool trial to choose from.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, since i am still setting this up, I end up deleteing the mysites and doing it all again with positive results. I only had 3 users with mysites but this is for 1500 users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the Personal Site from the User Profile dropdown.

1. Click "Manage User Profiles"
2. Find the profile of the user by searching
3. Click on it and select "Delete User's Personal Site"
4. Click "Ok"